# android http post response into webview and navigate

Tags: android, http-post, webviewclient

i'm making an app that make a post request to Ilias server, I receive the response and open it on a webview, my problem is that if I navigate, when I click some link it doesn't save my credentials and teels me "You are not logged in" and dont continue.

Here is the code:

```
public class ilias extends Activity {

 WebView webView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://www.ilias.de/docu/login.php?client_id=docu");
        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "stacked")); //this username 
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "overflow"));//works


  try {
   UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
         request.setEntity(entity);

         HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(request);

   bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
   StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
   String line = "";
   String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator); 
   }
   bufferedReader.close();

   Toast.makeText(ilias.this, 
     "Finished", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   String webData = stringBuffer.toString();

   webView.loadData(webData,"text/html","UTF-8");
   webView.loadDataWithBaseURl("http://www.ilias.de/docu/",webData,"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(ilias.this, 
     e.toString(), 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(ilias.this, 
     e.toString(), 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }finally{
   if (bufferedReader != null){
    try {
     bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing a POST this way you're losing the ability to store cookies. You will have to also emulate the authentication mechanism from the server in the `WebView`.  You can directly use POST from WebView with a request body. It appears you're passing the Username and Password via a URL encoded entity which is comptible with the WebView's [post method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#postUrl%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D%29).

Try something like:

```
String query = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password";
webview.postUrl("http://www.ilias.de/docu/login.php?client_id=docu", query.getBytes());
```

Comment: but when should i call the postUrl method?

Comment: continue doing the same thing. Always a click a link i get "You are not logged in". You can test the code, username and password works.

Comment: I keep getting webpage not available when i tried to open the link on a device, works in a browser

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the cookies by httpclient if you are using httppost multiple times. If you are just navigating in a website then the website actually should be storing your information since it it something that is handled by the website, otherwise make httpclient a public static global and share it either throughout your activity or though other activities.